# week view, fc-event-title missing

Tags: fullcalendar

In week view, events that occupy only a slot are generated like

```
<div class="fc-event-time">13:20 - EventTitle</div>
```

(instead of time-range), and

```
<div class="fc-event-content"></div>
```

so, no <fc-event-title> is inserted in the content.

This can be patched in eventRender, but I wonder if this is a bug or a feature.

Tnx.

Comment: How did you patched? I find this behaviour inconvenient...

Comment: @Azahoth: it is a feature; in fullcalendar.js (line: 3863):


`if (seg.contentTop !== undefined && height - seg.contentTop < 10) {
    // not enough room for title, put it in the time header`

So in that case there is no `.fc-event-title` inside `.fc-event-content`.

What I meant is you could use `eventRender: function(calev, elt, view)` to "patch" whatever you want in `elt`.

Comment: @Azathoth
... to "patch" elt and display it as needed.

Comment: I've found it, thank you. I where looking for examples on how define custom renderer rather than modify the source code. Having a oneliner text is useful when there is no room to have two lines, my users where complaining about having events titles vith different font sizes. At the end I solved via css forcing (actually removing a rule) the same size on .fc-event-title and .fc-event-time